# Java application launcher

Tags: java

I have written a very simple Java application. Can anyone tell me how to create a launcher like icon to run that application both in Ubuntu and Windows ??

Thanks in advance..!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An [executable JAR](http://csdl.ics.hawaii.edu/~johnson/613f99/modules/04/jar-files.html) should work fine for a launcher on both Windows and Linux. However, that won't get you a custom icon.

On Windows, you can use [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/), which will create a `.exe` wrapper around your JAR file. The JSmooth program will let you create an icon for the EXE as well (it also has options such as getting the user to download the necessary version of the JVM, or only permitting one instance of the program to run).

Answer (score 2):

If your java application is to be distributed from a web server, you should have a look at Java Web Start which can do what you ask for based on a JNLP-file.  Notably see

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javaws/developersguide/faq.html#104

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu and Windows will both have different ways to launch the application.  I see two routes to follow here.  One is to use Java Web Start and use a web interface to start your application.  The other is to search for some sort of 3rd party installer that will create setup/installation programs for all the platforms you want to use.

I actually used a third party install program before, InstallAnywhere, but it was almost ten years ago.  It offered the functionality you are looking for, though.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to do this, sometimes the simplest is the best approach.  One solution as suggested is a simple starting script.  Roll your application into a jar, then include a script that does nothing more than `"java -jar myscript.jar"`.  I do this all the time for internal customers that may be running various types of *nix and whatever version of windows (a few macs as well).  How sophisticated you need it to be depends on the audience served.

Answer (score 0):

Create a bat/shell script which starts your application.
And than create a shortcut/launcher for it.

Shortcut file in windows has extension *lnk*.

### Update

See example - [SQuirreL launch file](http://squirrel-sql.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/squirrel-sql/trunk/sql12/app/cmd/).

Comment: The problem is there is no universal bat/shell script that will work for Unix and Windows.  Nor is there a universal method for creating the shortcut or launcher.

Comment: Sure, you have to create two scripts. You can take a look how it's done in SQuirreL.